# TypeError: leftClick() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Python, and am trying to create a log in window. When the user types in their username and password, the program will retrieve the set username and password that was saved into a text file, and if they match the user will be able to use the program. However, I keep getting this message when trying to run the program. Here is my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    login = Tk()
    Label(login, text ="Username").grid(row = 0)
    Label(login, text ="Password").grid(row = 1)

    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    i1 = Entry(login, textvariable=username)
    i2 = Entry(login, textvariable=password, show = "*")

    i1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    i2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def leftClick(username, password):
            f = open('godhelpme.txt', 'r')
            file = open('some_file.txt', 'r')
            if username == (f.read()):
                    if password == (file.read()):
                            print ("HELLOOOO")
                    else:
                            print ("invalid username/password")
            else: print ("invalid username/password")


    button2 = Button(login, text = "Log In", command = save)
    button2.grid(columnspan = 2)
    button2.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)



    login.mainloop()
```

This is how I tried to put two functions for my button

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk


    def win1():
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = '3 3 12 12')
        mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
        mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = 'Register', command = register).grid(
            column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = 'Log In', command = login).grid(
            column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)

        root.mainloop()

    def combine_funcs(save, quit):
        def combined_func(save, quit):
            for f in funcs:
                f(save, quit)
        return combined_funcs

    def quit():
        root.withdraw()

    def register():
        quit()
        def save():
            import json as serializer
            with open('godhelpme.txt', 'w') as f:
                serializer.dump(username.get(), f)
            with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
                serializer.dump(password.get(), f)
            register.quit()

        register = Tk()
        Label(register, text ="Username").grid(row = 0)
        Label(register, text ="Password").grid(row = 1)

        username = StringVar()
        password = StringVar()

        e1 = Entry (register, textvariable=username)
        e2 = Entry (register, textvariable=password, show= "*")

        e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


        button1 = Button(register, text = "Register", command = combined_funcs(save, quit))
        button1.grid(columnspan = 2)
        button1.bind("<Button-1>")

        register.mainloop
```

Answer (score 1):

When binding the button, the callback function should be one that gets an event as an argument. tkinter doesn't know what you expect to get for username and password, so you cannot bind that kind of a function.

You need to create a callback function that gets the username and password the user input and then calls the `leftClick` function with these parameters.

Also using bind to <Button-1> is not necessary, since you don't need to know the coordinates of the click. You already have the `command = save` in your code, so it should call a function `save` when the button is pressed.

You probably want something like this, since you already bind the Entry widgets to the variables, so they are filled automatically:

```
def clickLogin():
        f = open('godhelpme.txt', 'r')
        file = open('some_file.txt', 'r')
        if username == (f.read()):
                if password == (file.read()):
                        print ("HELLOOOO")
                else:
                        print ("invalid username/password")
        else: print ("invalid username/password")


button2 = Button(login, text = "Log In", command = clickLogin)
button2.grid(columnspan = 2)
```

And no call to bind anything else on the button.

Comment: How do I create a callback function? I do apologise as I'm extremely new at this

Comment: I tried it and now it says "TypeError: clickLogin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'"

Comment: @ninjedi Sorry, mixed up the callback types. Removed the argument, commands don't take any arguments.

Comment: It seems to be working now, thanks! Do you by any chance know how to add two commands for a button? I've tried a few methods and none seem to work

Comment: @ninjedi Running two functions on click? You'll have to make one function that calls them both, you can't add two commands to one Button

Comment: I'll post the code in the question to show you what I did